# Finding the size of a matrix representing a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a question from a past linear algebra final exam. I am trying to find the range and kernel of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ represented by $T(x)=Ax$, where $A$ is the matrix
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
    2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

<s>I can find the range by finding the column space of $A$, which are just the vectors $(1,2,0)^T$ and $(0,1,1)^T$. I can find the kernel by solving the equation $Ax=0$ which has only the trivial solution. Therefore, T is one-to-one. For $T$ to be onto, the rank of $T$ must equal the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and since the rank is 2, $T$ is also onto. Since it is both onto and one-to-one, $T$ is also an isomorphism.</s>

However, I don't understand how a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^5$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented by a 3x5 matrix. Applying the transformation on each column of the identity matrix should produce an image in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but how can this be if each column in this matrix has 3 elements? I see that each column has a zero, but this still doesn't make sense to me since the second and third columns have a z element. It is possible this was a typo in the question if no one has an answer.

Comment: The transformation is not invertible since the matrix is not square so it cannot be both one-to-one and onto which is equivalent to invertibility of the function. Bijective functions will also take basis vectors to basis vectors so if they are invertible the domain and image of the function must have the same dimension which is another way to tell that the transformation is not bijective.

Comment: You’re right. It sure looks like there’s a typo in the question. It’s much likelier that it’s supposed to have $T:\mathbb R^5\to\mathbb R^3$ than that someone stuck an extra row onto the matrix.

Comment: I found the mistake, I think T is onto but not one-to-one. I did not solve Ax=0 originally, I used the vectors of the column space thinking it would be the same thing. When you try to solve Ax=0 it is clear there are infinite solutions, so A is not one-to-one. Is it always the case that going from Rn to Rm where n>m will always be an onto transformation? And if n<m, will it never be onto?

Comment: Also, if the question is supposed to say R3 instead of R2 then it would neither be one-to-one nor onto since  the dimension of the range wouldn't match the dimension of R3. Since I don't understand how a 3x5 matrix could represent a transformation to R2, the most likely scenario to me is that it is neither  one-to-one nor onto and there is a typo.

Comment: You've already ascertained that it should be $\mathbb{R}^3$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$, but you still have some substantial errors above. In particular, $Ax=0$ does not have only the trivial solution; for example $A(1,0,0,-1, 0) = 0$ (there are infinitely many other nontrivial solutions). A lesser error, but still one you ought to correct is that $Col(A)$ is *not* those two vectors, but rather the *span* of them; the distinction really does matter.

Comment: Missed your comment where you noticed $T$ was not one to one. To answer your question about onto, $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, n>m$ does not imply onto. For example let $Tx = 0$ for every $x$; $T$ is clearly not onto.

Comment: What you *can* say is that if $n>m$, then $T$ is not one-to-one. (It may or may not be onto.) Similarly, if $n<m$, then $T$ is not onto. (Here, it may or may not be one-to-one.)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, this answer summarizes the answers to the exam question and your questions and the comments.  I assume that $T:\Bbb R^5 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3.$

The range of $T$ is the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ spanned by
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$
$T$ is not onto because $\Bbb R^3$ has three dimensions, so the image $T$ would require three linearly-independent spanning vectors.

You know how to find the kernel of $T,$ so I will just give an answer: It is the subspace of $\Bbb R^5$ spanned by
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} -2\\  0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix},
          \begin{bmatrix} -1\\  0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix},
          \begin{bmatrix}  0\\ -1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$
As a partial check on the answer, we see that the dimensions of the range and kernel sum to the dimension of $V.$

A linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ with $n > m$ is not one-to-one and may or may not be onto. If $n < m,$ $T$ is not onto and may or may not be one-to-one.  In neither case is $T$ one-to-one.